# How do I authenticate proxy network when using postman native App?

Tags: postman, proxy-authentication

I am using postman native app on windows machine(Version 6.0.9). There is no option for me to set proxy user name and password under settings>>Proxy. only i have an option set Proxy Server. Also postman app is not taking chrome/system proxy authentication settings unlike Postman extension. Hence i am unable to connect to web server outside my corporate network. Can someone please help. Much appreciated!

Comment: Sometimes doing `<username>:<password>@<server>` works. Sometimes it doesn't, I find it depends on the network.